# SPI device sniffing/mirror feature

Tags: spi

I have an an embedded Linux ARM board, where an application opens the `/dev/spidev1.0` device and constantly talks through with another MCU.
Now, if I I try to look at what exchanges (that's what I'd need), doing
a hexdump `/dev/spidev1.0` shows something in the beginning but causes the application to crash. The app is very sensitive and I think it crashes because the app uses and it can't be used for viewing simultaneously.

Would there be a way to create an alias, or something like a mirror of this device if I write some extra code/driver? Or is there no chance for me to sniff the traffic like that (in software) ?

Rewrote:

```
int ioctl(int fd, unsigned long request, struct spi_ioc_transfer *xfer)
```

But, `gcc` output the following error:

```
myioctl.c:6:5: error: conflicting types for ‘ioctl’ In file included from myioctl.c:1:0: /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/include/s‌​ys/ioctl.h:41:12: note: previous declaration of ‘ioctl’ was here
```

Any help how the original definition:

```
/* Perform the I/O control operation specified by REQUEST on FD.
   One argument may follow; its presence and type depend on REQUEST.
   Return value depends on REQUEST.  Usually -1 indicates error.  */

extern int ioctl (int __fd, unsigned long int __request, ...) __THROW;
```

could be overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this Linux distribution does support LD_PRELOAD you can easily use this feature to override opening/closing/reading/writing/ioctl-ing  functions to this specific device.
See here for very basic tutorial: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/

This will not require writing driver and pretty usable approach.
IN addition you can try to use [strace](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/) utility to trace all IO system calls which will obviously include the accesses to your device.

Comment: Thanks! I have been using strace, however: The app is relying heavily on IPC communications and it is sensitive to debugging by attaching to the process. So by attaching directly with strace -p, it crashes in a while. While if I stop it and start it with strace, it relies on an IPC channel hookup which doesn't work properly if it is just started by hand.

Many thanks for the LD_PRELOAD. Is it also possible to display variables? What I would really need is to printf some vars. I read this too beforehand. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33340/Code-Injection-into-Running-Linux-Application

Comment: Using LD_PRELOAD requires you to write .so library which intercepts specific calls to library functions (read/write/open and probably ioctl in your case). You definitely can call printf like functions inside your implementation.

Comment: Just a little bit more help on overriding the ioctl call in a .so. The definition in the ioctl.h is 
extern int ioctl (int __fd, unsigned long int __request, ...) __THROW;

So there is that optional parameter, which is the one called to actually receive or send data. Rewrote: int ioctl(int fd, unsigned long request, struct spi_ioc_transfer *xfer), gcc says:
myioctl.c:6:5: error: conflicting types for ‘ioctl’
In file included from myioctl.c:1:0:
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/include/sys/ioctl.h:41:12: note: previous declaration of ‘ioctl’ was here

Comment: I'm not pretty sure that I understand the question, but I found the example that will probably suit your needs: https://github.com/poliva/ldpreloadhook